# SqlAlchemy Database Model: Access Column Enum value

Tags: python, flask, enums, sqlalchemy

In model I have:

```
class GenderEnum(enum.Enum):
    man = "ﻡﺭﺩ"
    woman = "ﺰﻧ"

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Gender
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum(GenderEnum), unique=False, default="man")
```

Then I am trying to define a custom converter for `mode_form` method which extract the enum value as a label used to show a field in WTForm

```
@converts('Enum')
def conv_Enum(self, column, field_args, **extra):
    if 'choices' not in field_args:
        field_args['choices'] = [(e, e) for e in column.type.enums]
        assert False, field_args["choices"] 
    return f.SelectField(**field_args)
```

However, I don't know how to access the values (مرد , زن) here to populate (key, value) for `choices`

Answer (score 1):

(First: My Unsolicited Opinion)
**Why you shouldn't be able to access them anyway:**
When you create an Enum column, the known values of that column for the database (and the model) will be set equal to the *name* of the Enum variables (the name of the constant variables, not the value of them). So it doesn't make any sense for the value of the Enum variables to be known to the Enum column, because in the first place, you were trying to convert the `(مرد , زن)` to `(woman, man)`.

---

**Workaround**
My way of doing this would be something like the following:

1. Define the Enum class INSIDE the class of the model.
2. Access the Enum class using `column.class_.GenderEnum`

So your refactored codes would be:

```py
# model.py
class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    class GenderEnum(enum.Enum):
        man = "ﻡﺭﺩ"
        woman = "ﺰﻧ"

    __tablename__ = 'Users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Gender
    gender = db.Column(db.Enum(GenderEnum), unique=False, default="man")

# <your_other_file>.py
@converts('Enum')
def conv_Enum(self, column, field_args, **extra):
    if 'choices' not in field_args:
        field_args['choices'] = [(e.name, e.value) for e in column.class_.GenderEnum]
        assert False, field_args["choices"] 
    return f.SelectField(**field_args)
```

Note that `(e.name, e.value)` would result in `(man, مرد)` and `(woman, زن)`.